# Fetch Parent even when child is absent

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

After many attempts I'm here to seek a help from any of you. A solution is very much needed.

I have a parent (Patient) entity and its child (Address) entity.
Where I want to fetch all the registered patients and address details, where address details may be null. Meaning, Patient may not have address details..

I have written logic by using CriteriaBuilder like this

```
    CriteriaBuilder builder = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Object[]> query = builder.createQuery(Object.class);

    Root<TaskImpl> patientRoot = query.from(Patient.class);
    Root<ContentImpl> addressRoot = query.from(Address.class);
    query.multiselect(patientRoot.get("patinetId"),patientRoot .get("patinetName"),
                       addressRoot.get("city));

    Predicate patAddressJoinPred = builder.equal(
            patientRoot.get("patientId"),
            addressRoot.get("patient").get("patientId"));


    query.where(builder.and(patAddressJoinPred));
```

please find Patient and Address entities for your ref,

```
Patient.java-----------------
@Entity
public class Patinet{
@Id
private Long patentId;
private String patientName;
}
------------------------------
```

```
Address.java------------------
@Entity
public class Address{
@Id
private Long addressId;
private String city;
@OneToOne(FetchType.Lazy)
@JoinColumn("patinet_id")
private Patient patient;
}
-------------------------------
```

But after the criteria builder, I have applied cross join on Address entity which will be a performance problem and I cannot get details of patients which don't have address details..

for simplicity, the sample data and my required output is given bellow.

```
Patient table 
-------------
id | name
-------------
1  | Sameul
2  | Jhon
3  | khan
4  | Lee

-------------
```

```
Address table 
-----------------------
id | city  | patient_id
-----------------------
1  | Blz   |    1
2  | Stn   |    3
```

required out put

```
-------------------------
id |  patientName  | city
-------------------------
1  |   Sameul      | blz
2  |    Jhon       |
3  |    khan       | stn
4  |    Lee        |
```

But getting like this

```
-------------------------
id |  patientName  | city
-------------------------
1  |   Sameul      | blz
3  |    khan       | stn
-------------------------
```

Will be waiting for your valuable solution
Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

It looks you are using `inner join`, you should use `outer joins`
Something like,

```
final Root<Patient> patient = criteriaQuery.from(Patient.class);
Join<Patient, Address> join1 = patient .join("joinColumnName", JoinType.LEFT);

Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(Address.<String> get("patient_id"), patient;
criteria.add(predicate);
criteriaQuery.where(predicate);
criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
```

Hope it resolves your query. I have not tested it but should work fine.

Comment: No, It didn't help